# Why isn't this code running? (I'm new to coding)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm pretty new to coding, I just started learning python one day ago. I tried to write this code because I saw something similar on a website once. (I can't remember which one) But the code is somehow not running.

```
def getNumber():
    result = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    return result 

def Main():
    print("test")

    output = getNumber()
    print(output)

if __name__ = "__main__":
    Main()
```

It's supposed to be printing the number that you type. There's no error message and I'm pretty confused at the moment.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Post your output, can u see test at least?

Comment: You want `if __name__ == "__main__":` you need to use `==` to test for equality. Vote to close as this is a typo

Comment: As stated quite a few times before, you assigned the wrong operator. For future projects it is very handy to know that python (and virtually every other language) returns errors in the following format `<type> <reference> <additional info>` the type tells you what you did wrong, like referenced a variable before you assigned a value to it. The place tells you where, line 1, 2, 3 and so forth and the additional info can tell you more about what you did wrong. Error messages are your biggest friend when debugging!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot a `==` instead of a `=` in `__name__ = "__main__":`, use this instead:

```
def getNumber():
  result = int(input("Enter a number: "))
  return result

def Main():
  print("test")

output = getNumber()
print(output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  Main()
```

Expected program output:

```
test
Enter a number: 5
5
```

Also, you don't have to over-complicate things, you could just use:

```
print("test")
result = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using the assignment operator (`=`) instead of an equals operator (`==`).

Assignment operators (`==`) are used to assign values to names:

```
my_name = "LogicalBranch"
```

While the equals operator (`==`) are to determine if a value is equal to another:

```
1 == 1 # Expected output: True
2 == 1 # Expected output: False
```

The solution would be to change your last two lines from this:

```
if __name__ = "__main__":
  Main()
```

To this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  Main()
```

Another tip is to use the [PEP8 convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) when naming function and variables, so it might make more sense to name your `main` function `main` instead of `Main`.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This `if __name__ = "__main__":`

should be `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Answer (score 0):

`=` is used to declare variables.
`==` is what you use to compare (as in an if clause)

Try changing it.

Answer (score 0):

Every one is saying to put this "=="

Just remember when you do this "=" it is assigning a value to the name
But when you do this "==" it checks if it is equal to that value

If that makes sense